# Why sometimes source formatting does not work?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36063562/edit). Code indented 4 spaces - not being properly formatted (link to edit, to verify that it is indented 4 spaces).

What's the reason?

Comment: Give it some more spaces!

Comment: Right, that did it, but...why?

Comment: Because code loves spaces... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3792

Comment: not a bug, problem is that you need an additional level of indentation because it's in a list.